# javascript node.js getting line number in try catch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, try-catch

I'm using try catch on a node.js script:

```js
try {} catch (err) {console.log(err)}
```

I get an output like this:

```js
{ 
  stack: [Getter/Setter],
  arguments: [ 'undefined' ],
  type: 'called_non_callable',
  message: [Getter/Setter]
}
```

Is there an easy way to make this more informative? Include line numbers and function names and such?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Those `[Getter/Setter]` members indicate further information available on the error object. You can easily dump the contents of those getters/setters using a small helper function (very trivial implementation, further refinement is up to you)

```
function dumpError(err) {
  if (typeof err === 'object') {
    if (err.message) {
      console.log('\nMessage: ' + err.message)
    }
    if (err.stack) {
      console.log('\nStacktrace:')
      console.log('====================')
      console.log(err.stack);
    }
  } else {
    console.log('dumpError :: argument is not an object');
  }
}

try {
  not_defined.function_call();
} catch(err) {
  dumpError(err);
}
```

You could also extend the `Object.prototype` for improved accessibility (so you could use err.dumpError()), although extending `Object.prototype` bears the risk of overwriting existing functionality.

Comment: Real life changer, ty

Comment: How to get a deeper level err.stack?