# Throwing errors in jQuery plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

When developing your own jQuery plugins, is there a standard or a preferred way to throw errors? Should I just use `jQuery.error()`? Should I first set it, e.g. `jQuery.error = console.error` or leave it set to the default?

EDIT: To be clear, errors meant for the developer, not the user. I assume the developer should be handling all errors and my plugin should just return certain values if things fail.

Comment: Do not assume `console` exists! Older versions of IE will ruin you. `if (typeof console !== 'undefined') { ... }` . Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484528/what-are-the-best-practices-for-javascript-error-handling)

Comment: Good thing I don't support older versions of IE! ;) But point noted.