# Generic error handling in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using interceptor in my app for generic error handling when service is down
I am getting success response with status 200 even i have changed the base url to test my service. What am i doing wrong??

```
      var myServices = angular.module('myServices', ['ngResource']);

       myServices.config(function ($provide, $httpProvider) {
       $provide.factory('ErrorInterceptor', function ($q) {
       return {
        response: function(){
        return response;// always success??
       }
        responseError: function(rejection) {
        $scope.addErrorAlert("Services are currently not responding.  Please try again later.",true);
            return;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: The reason you are getting `$http undefined error` is that you are returning nothing to the responseError function. Return a value to that function. Better yet, return the rejection for **chaining**.

Answer (score 1):

the best way to add interceptor in `$httpProvider` is to create a separate factory for that and push the same into `$httpProvider.interceptors`

```
var myServices = angular.module('myServices', ['ngResource']);

myServices.factory('ErrorInterceptor', function ($q) {
    return {
        responseError: function (response) {
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };

})
myServices.config(function ($httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('ErrorInterceptor');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use interceptors to write global exception handler. You just need to override responseError interceptor. Here i called "openErrorModel" method defined on $rootScope to open error model with error message when ever there is error.
This would be cleaner and modularized. and you can avoid duplication this way.

Sample code:

```
(function (global) {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("TestAPp").factory('httpInterceptor', ["$rootScope", "$q", function ($rootScope, $q) {
        return {
        responseError: function (response) {
            /* Open Error model and display error */
            $rootScope.openErrorModel(response);
            /* reject deffered object so that it'll reach error block , else it'll execute success function */
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
        };
    }]);

}(this));
```

//registering interceprtor

```
(function (global) {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("TestApp", [])
           .config([ '$httpProvider',function ($httpProvider) {
                /* Register the interceptor */
                $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');

    }]);

}(this));
```

PS: My openErrorModel definition

```
$rootScope.openErrorModel = function (error) {
      $rootScope.errorMessage = error.data;
      $('#errorModal').modal('show');
};
```

You can refer to [Error Handling in angular](http://mysoftwareexperience.blogspot.in/2016/02/error-handling-and-authentication-with.html) for more info.