# Does node.js have anything like __file__ and __line__ like the c++ preprocessor macros?

Tags: node.js

I'm working on enhancing logging in some node.js applications.  In the past have used C++'s __ file__ and __ line __ preprocessor macros to help us track down issues when logging events.  I haven't found anything similar to it in the node.js world.

Does anyone have suggestions or know how I can get line number and file name in node.js for logging purposes?

I'm looking for something like:

```
console.log(__FILE__ + "." + __LINE__ + "\t" + new Date().toISOString() + " Message ");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See: [Accessing line number in V8 JavaScript (Chrome & Node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386492/accessing-line-number-in-v8-javascript-chrome-node-js)

Then for a filename:

```
Object.defineProperty(global, '__file', {
  get: function(){
    return __stack[1].getFileName().split('/').slice(-1)[0];
  }
});
```

You could also just use the `process.argv[1]` instead of calling the `__stack` getter but I wanted to keep it similar.

Answer (score 16):

see the [global object](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html):

```
__filename
```

for the lineNumber see this post: [javascript node.js getting line number in try catch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802840/javascript-node-js-getting-line-number-in-try-catch)

Answer (score 4):

Expanded on the previous answers a bit into here: https://gist.github.com/gavinengel/8572856

Allows setting globals: __line, __file, __ext, __dir

By the way, how do I create?: __function, __method, __class

Comment: Thanks for the gist.  You should consider making this into a node module, it could be a nice npm module

Comment: Sure.  Actually, I'd recommend you check out this code which I just realized was out there by the PHPJS team: https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/tree/master/experimental/language

Answer (score 2):

Just use the C preprocesor, adds an extra build step to your code but then it allows stripping out your logging for production code.

Comment: Not a bad idea. Never thought about that.

Comment: Sounds good, but how, exactly does one "just use the C preprocessor"?