# ist there something like __FILE__ in coffeescript at 'compiletime'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, coffeescript

The question:

How do I get somthing like that in coffeescript

```
modules_list[some_calculation(__FILE__)]=a_local_class.new
```

I have a module manager, that handles all my coffeescripts (js) at runtime - i.e. while in browser, that means:

I have

- many modules, not all are in all situations loaded 'statically'
- only some have dependencies
- module manager resolves things like init and dynamic reload (ajax)
  and dynamic init

A module looks like this in prinzip:

```
class Book
    constructor: ->
        ...

    init: =>
        $$$.get_module('BookReader') #<- ajax loaded if not already

    later_on: => 
        $$$.get_module('LetterCounter').count_letters(@) #<- ajax loaded if not already

    ...


@$$$.modules_list['Book'] = ->
    new Book
```

this all works (very) satisfying.

But I have a rendunancy in my Logic, because a 'module', has a module name, a class name and - thats the point - a file name

the class name is - thats clear - not a problem, I could name all 'Foo'. Its only not nice to do that.

But modulename ( modules_list['Book'] ) and the coffee- (js-) file name are redundant in sence of Rails CoC.

Any ideas how to get

```
@$$$.modules_list[some_calc(__FILE__)] = -> new Book
```

i was [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591785/does-node-js-have-anything-like-file-and-line-like-the-c-preprocessor), and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591785/does-node-js-have-anything-like-file-and-line-like-the-c-preprocessor) may be a solution for me, but if, I dont understand it.

thanks in advance

ps.: for those who want to know "why I do this":

I have 3 completely different apps for 3 different customers, I am far away to say what is the base for all, 2 apps a realy big with a huge amount of js, that is not always needed so I *want* to reload it dynamicaly. I "help" asset pipeline a bit with putting all files (staticaly) used in a single one without the ones I was working on the last 20 mins  (dynamicaly) for better debugging, and I get rid of all (down-)load ordering problems

Comment: Why does it need to happen at compiletime?  Does `module.filename` work?

Comment: @AaronDufour: I think that only at compile time, the information is available, because after that its typical within a "md5-somthing.js", and the original name of the file is maximal in a comment somewhere. oops, could this be a solution? Or do you think about a generator? There is no module.filename

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "There is no module.filename".  Are you running some ancient version of node?  It's even [documented](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_filename).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `__FILE__`or something like that, in that case. I see that now. It would be the wrong direction of naming.

Its the same 'problem' that you have with Rails it self. If you have

```
module Base
   class Fun
```

your filename should be `base/fun.rb` not vice versa!

The Filename resolves out of "its content" not the other direction.